# Comments in script files

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to write comments into files specified by `-filter_script` and `-filter_complex_script`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-filter_script` and `-filter_complex_script` simply read a filtergraph from a file, and there is no support for comments within filtergraphs.